# Take several elements from the array, like with "foreach"

Tags: php, arrays

How can I take several elements from the array at once? Like `foreach` is for only one, how can I get more than one in each iteration?

```
$data = array(1,2,3,4,5,6);
foreach($data as $a and $b) // pseudocode
{
    echo $a + $b;
}
```

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Is it always the next element you want to get too? Or do you want to get more than two elements in each iteration? Are they always siblings or is it another pattern?

Comment: @insertusernamehere, next to each other. They are like associative array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try

```
$data = array(1,2,3,4,5,6);
echo "<pre>";
```

`foreach` loop using [`array_chunk`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php)

```
foreach ( array_chunk($data, 2) as $v ) {
    $v[1] = isset($v[1]) ? $v[1] : 0;
    echo $v[0] + $v[1], PHP_EOL;
}
```

`For` Loop

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i += 2) {
    $v = isset($data[$i + 1]) ? $data[$i + 1] : 0;
    echo $data[$i] + $v, PHP_EOL;
}
```

`while` loop

```
$i = 0;
while($v = array_slice($data, $i, 2)){
    $v[1] = isset($v[1]) ? $v[1] : 0;
    echo $v[0] + $v[1], PHP_EOL;
    $i += 2;
}
```

Output

```
3
7
11
```

Comment: The `array_chunk` version is definitely nice.

Comment: I think you still have to use `isset` on the `+1` item. Otherwise It can result in a warning. `array_chunk` is really nice.

Comment: `array_chunk` - php really has everything

Comment: @Qiao its greatest strength, and its greatest weakness ;)

Comment: @Qiao just added `array_slice` to the list ... PHP has too many function which can do the same thing

Answer (score 2):

Use a normal `for` loop and increment your index twice each time. You can generalize this by incrementing the index by the number of elements you want.

```
// Note that if count($data) is not even, then we'll miss the last element
for($i = 0; ($i + 1) < count($data); $i += 2) {
    $first = $data[$i];
    $second = $data[$i + 1];
}
```

Comment: You may want to add a check to be sure [$i+1] exists as well, in case there are an odd number of elements in the array

Comment: @KelvinMackay Yeah just thought of that.

Comment: I think you still have to use `isset` on the `+1` item. Otherwise I wcan result in a warning.

Comment: @insertusernamehere I'm checking that `($i + 1) < count($data)`, so `$data[$i+1]` is guaranteed to be a valid index.

Comment: Ah you've edited your answer while I was writing. :) So this solution is fine. But works, as you've stated only on an even amount of items. :)

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge there's no native way to do that - your best bet is to use a for loop and tweak the index to select items as per your requirements.  i.e. something like:

```
for ($i = 1; $i < count($data)-1; $i++) {
    for ($j = $i; $j < count($data); $j++) {
        echo $data[$i] + $data[$j];
    }
}
```

or

```
for ($i = 1; $i < count($data); $i+=2) {
    echo $data[$i] + $data[$i+1];
}
```

NB: the second option has a problem with odd numbers of elements in the array.